# Timeshift tags in Ubuntu

Tags: backup, timeshift

Here is the screenshot of my backups in TimeShift:

[image: screenshot of backups in timeshift]

What are the TimeShift tags like 'O', 'D'?

Comment: Point at any of the tags and it'll give you a list of what they mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tags available are Weekly, Daily, Monthly, Boot, Hourly, and Other.

- W Weekly. This is a snapshot taken weekly.
- D Daily. This is a snapshot taken daily.
- H Hourly. This is a snapshot taken hourly.
- M Monthly. This is a snapshot taken monthly.
- B Boot. This is a snapshot taken at boot.
- O Other. This is usually when you've triggered the snapshot manually.

Note that O can also trigger/take the place of a regularly scheduled backup and so you can get two tags for the same backup.

Comment: Isn't O for On-demand backup?